# Apple iCloud - Can somebody explain

Tags: iphone, cloud, cloud-hosting, icloud

So is Apple iCloud a competitor for other data storage frameworks such as Core Data?

To be honest I'm not entirely sure how it works. I am currently building an app and was going to use a database to store and load data, but am I right in thinking that iCloud could be used in such a way, to act as a database?

Comment: Ask this in the dev forums if you want a real answer as no one here can give anything more than speculation based on the keynote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the other hand, if you use Core Data, iCloud can potentially sync your data across devices...

...And now that we're past the NDA period, see [iCloud document here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html)... (look for Using iCloud in Conjunction with Databases) and [the release notes here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html):

Answer (score 2):

Most iCloud developer information is still under NDA, so we can't discuss it deeply here, but based just on the public information, iCloud is not a database and so does not really intersect with Core Data. iCloud is a way to sync documents.

Comment: So that would mean it is intended for apps that store files locally on Apple devices?

Comment: That's a fair assessment. The highlevel is covered here: http://developer.apple.com/icloud. And the lower-level is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html

Comment: Although iCloud is not a database, there is actually substantial integration with CoreData via a document class that is essentially a Core Data store, where Core Data manages merges from multiple devices.

Answer (score -3):

Watch the last [keynote](http://events.apple.com.edgesuite.net/11piubpwiqubf06/event/), Steve Jobs explains iCloud pretty  well.